# Specifying input for a batch photoshop job

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing

In the next 2 months, I will be helping local artists sell their work on various product types (tees, canvases, hoodies, etc.). They will be sending me high resolution PNG files which I need to obviously apply to the various product types.

I want to automate this as much as possible (keeping in mind that things like hoodies can come in 10+ different colors, for each gender, etc. so this could take A LOT of time). I have found this script that should handle most of the heavy lifting (including the naming, which would ideally be something like "design-name_hoodie_yellow_male.jpg" with the Photoshop group names being used as subfolders like hoodies, tees, etc.)

```
https://github.com/jwa107/Photoshop-Export-Layers-to-Files-Fast
```

However, since I could also be receiving 20+ PNGs per day, I would like to put them in a folder and have the batch job scan it for new artwork and apply it to a smart object area in the PSD, is this possible?

Any suggestions (or how you would do it to save time) would be appreciated!

P.S: The input doesn't have to be PNG but the output must be jpg as I will be putting these designs on an eCommerce site. When the item goes for printing, the company will receive the full, uncompressed file (not the jpgs).

Comment: Not really applicable to your immediate concern for automation, but "high res PNG" doesn't exist and at least in your example you have them becoming JPG which is even worse for printing something like this. Are you sure about these file types?

Comment: The input doesn't have to be PNG but the output must be jpg as I will be putting these designs on an eCommerce site. When the item goes for printing, the company will receive the full, uncompressed file (not the jpgs). Hope that clears things up, thanks for your response :)

Comment: It's possible but I would like to know what you've tried?

Comment: Hey @Sgtmullet, could you [edit] that info into your question. It's pretty vital, and might be missed by potential answerers when it's in a comment like that. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely nothing but as I mentioned in my question, I am just looking for info at this point and don't expect solutions. I will post a job to get this done soon, thank you :)

Comment: @PieBie Thanks for the heads up, that was a good idea, thank you!